# Problem Using HttpClient Class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpclient, java-11

I'm trying to use a class from the Java 11 SDK but I'm having problems integrating it to my android studio. I have downloaded the Java 11 SDK from oracle, changed my build Gradle files to the targeted version but still is not working. Any ideas or step by step instruction on how to integrate Java 11?

EDIT:

Thanks to @hata, I found out that the class I wanted to use is no longer supported by Android Studio and have to use, HttpURLConnection instead.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

```
error: package java.net.http does not exist
 import java.net.http.HttpClient;
```

Here is my build Gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-R'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 'R'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion = '30.0.0 rc2'

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I think Android supports features of Java 7 and partly of Java 8. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: @hata your comment is not related to the question

Comment: You mean **Android 11** but **Java 11**?

Comment: @hata I am trying to use the HttpClient Class, with is a class from Java 11 but android studio is not recognising the class. I have the latest version of Andorid Studio

Comment: HttpClient had been removed since Android 6.0 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client I think we cannot entirely use Java features in Android programming.

Comment: If I mistake your intent, sorry...

Comment: @hata I did not realize that it was removed. I discovered the alternative class HttpURLConnection. I will research on how to use this class. Thank you very much you have answered my question.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck! :)

Comment: Don't confuse the Apache HttpClient with the Java 11 HttpClient - these are two different and unrelated APIs.